# Recursive inside recursive and the addition

Tags: python, recursion

I looked up this question but could not find an answer really. I just cannot wrap my head around the logic in this recursion example;

```
def f(s):
 if len(s) <= 1:
    return s
 return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0] #Note double recursion
```

I tried to list the steps but I do not know if we actually do add s[0] first and then pass it to f(s) again. Would someone be able to explain this step by step or in a clean way?

Thanks,

Comment: `s[0]` is not added first. It is added *last*. `f(s[1:])` is calculated, then the result passed to `f()` again, and *only then* is `s[0]` added.

Comment: `pdb` is your friend. add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` somewhere and check what's going on in there

Comment: I've tried running this on a list of integers and a list of strings.  Both fault on the first call, as we're trying to add an element to a list.  Please check the code you provided and try again.  Do you have a sample run?

Comment: It looks like the code works on a string, but not on a list

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you for confirming that. I figured that part. I am just  trying to list out the steps a bit more clearly. I do sort of understand the logic, just need a more clean explanation than the one I have in my head to fully understand this subject.

Comment: @Prune: it works on strings; try `'abc'` and `'abcd'` for example. Odd vs. even number of number characters matter here.

Comment: @zehnpaard: it's true the function shown doesn't work with lists, but a tiny change to the return statement fixes that: use `+ s[:1]` instead of `+ s[0]`.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion, and this is meant as at least a partial answer: my decorator [log_calls](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/log_calls) will show you what's going on, especially if you use the parameters `indent=True` and `log_retval=True`. I'm days away from releasing 0.3.0, which can decorate entire classes & hierarchies too -- it's done-done except for the docs.

Comment: Another hint: when you call `f(s)` with nonempty `s`, the total number of calls to `f` equals `2**len(s) - 1`, just like Towers of Hanoi. By induction on len(s), using the fact that `len(f(s))` equals `len(s)` for all s (obvious, but really a preliminary induction on len(s)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's a succinct way to describe what this is doing.  However, I broke it down into understandable pieces and inserted print statements for a thorough trace.

```
def f(s):
    print "ENTER, s=", s
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return_val = s
        print "(1)  len <= 1; return", return_val
    else:
        print "(2a) len >  1; recur"
        first_call = f(s[1:])
        print "(2b) len >  1; first_call:", first_call
        return_val = f(first_call) + s[0]
        print "(2c) len >  1; return", return_val
    print "LEAVE ...", s
    return return_val

print f('abc')
print f('abcd')
print f('0123456789')
```

Here is the output from the first two strings; the third is quite lengthy.

```
ENTER, s= abc
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= bc
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= c
(1)  len <= 1; return c
LEAVE ... c
(2b) len >  1; first_call: c
ENTER, s= c
(1)  len <= 1; return c
LEAVE ... c
(2c) len >  1; return cb
LEAVE ... bc
(2b) len >  1; first_call: cb
ENTER, s= cb
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= b
(1)  len <= 1; return b
LEAVE ... b
(2b) len >  1; first_call: b
ENTER, s= b
(1)  len <= 1; return b
LEAVE ... b
(2c) len >  1; return bc
LEAVE ... cb
(2c) len >  1; return bca
LEAVE ... abc
bca
ENTER, s= abcd
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= bcd
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= cd
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= d
(1)  len <= 1; return d
LEAVE ... d
(2b) len >  1; first_call: d
ENTER, s= d
(1)  len <= 1; return d
LEAVE ... d
(2c) len >  1; return dc
LEAVE ... cd
(2b) len >  1; first_call: dc
ENTER, s= dc
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= c
(1)  len <= 1; return c
LEAVE ... c
(2b) len >  1; first_call: c
ENTER, s= c
(1)  len <= 1; return c
LEAVE ... c
(2c) len >  1; return cd
LEAVE ... dc
(2c) len >  1; return cdb
LEAVE ... bcd
(2b) len >  1; first_call: cdb
ENTER, s= cdb
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= db
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= b
(1)  len <= 1; return b
LEAVE ... b
(2b) len >  1; first_call: b
ENTER, s= b
(1)  len <= 1; return b
LEAVE ... b
(2c) len >  1; return bd
LEAVE ... db
(2b) len >  1; first_call: bd
ENTER, s= bd
(2a) len >  1; recur
ENTER, s= d
(1)  len <= 1; return d
LEAVE ... d
(2b) len >  1; first_call: d
ENTER, s= d
(1)  len <= 1; return d
LEAVE ... d
(2c) len >  1; return db
LEAVE ... bd
(2c) len >  1; return dbc
LEAVE ... cdb
(2c) len >  1; return dbca
LEAVE ... abcd
dbca
```

Comment: You didn't have to instrument this by hand: [log_calls](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/log_calls) can do it for you. Yes I am the dev, but it really would have helped!

Comment: I understand; I checked out the link.  When we move to Python 3, we'll be using this in our testing.  I purposely didn't use it here to illustrate the principle.  I also grabbed a couple of intermediate values, but log_calls would have saved most of the time.

Comment: Understood, and thanks. Of course your answer is better off with no external dependencies. But if you ever have to do this again... and you may... :) Because I'm now updating the package, I had to mention that this is a great example of the kind of boilerplate code it saves you from writing.

Good luck/godspeed with your move to Py3!